# how i can get a <w:pict> tag from word document using open xml

Tags: c#, linq, openxml-sdk

i have a document which contains some `<w:pict>` tags in table.
how i can read/get it using openxml or XDocument
i want to Remove and then  Add updated `<w:pict>` tag in the document

```
 <w:tr w:rsidR="007F23F0" w:rsidTr="00773840">
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="4395" w:type="dxa" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="007F23F0" w:rsidP="00855D6B" w:rsidRDefault="007F23F0">
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Approver Signature:</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:fldSimple w:instr=" DOCPROPERTY  A1_Sign  \* MERGEFORMAT ">
          <w:r w:rsidR="00773840">
            <w:t>A1_Sign</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:fldSimple>
        <w:r w:rsidR="00773840">
          <w:pict>
            <v:shape id="_x0000_i1026" style="width:127.5pt;height:47.25pt" filled="t" o:preferrelative="f" type="#_x0000_t75" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
              <v:imagedata r:id="rId7" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" />
              <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="f" />
            </v:shape>
          </w:pict>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p w:rsidR="007F23F0" w:rsidP="00855D6B" w:rsidRDefault="007F23F0" />
      <w:p w:rsidR="007F23F0" w:rsidP="00855D6B" w:rsidRDefault="007F23F0" />
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
            {                    
                var run = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>().ToList();
                foreach (var eachrun in run)
                {              
                        var pic = eachrun.Descendants<Picture>().ToList();
                        foreach (var eachshape in pic)
                        {
                           --your code---
                        }                       
                }
            }
```